# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException for valid expression

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I get exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

for the line of code

```
when(messageSource.getMessage(eq(SUCCESS_MESSAGE_KEY), any(Object[].class), any(Locale.class))).thenReturn(anyString());
```

messageSource is of type org.springframework.context.MessageSource. Mockito version is 1.9.5. Can anyone guess what the problem is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot return `anyString()`, which is a matcher. It has to be a real string instance, like `"foo"`.

Comment: Thanks, that's was causing the problem